# Silex SecurityServiceProvider throws 'Identifier "security.authentication_providers" is not defined.'

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I can't figure out how to use `SecurityServiceProvider` in `Silex`. My configuration is:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/_admin/.+',
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/_admin/', 'check_path' => '/_admin/login_check'),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/_admin/logout'),
        'users' => array(
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsR...'),
        ),
    ),
);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
```

This just throws:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Identifier "security.authentication_providers" is not defined.'
```

According to the documentation in some cases when you want to access Security features outside of the handling of a request you have to call `$app->boot();` but this isn't my situation.
If I call `$app->boot();` before `$app->register(...)` it doesn't raise any exception but it probably doesn't boot at all because then in generating login form Twig throws:

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_admin_login_check" as such route does not exist.
```

There's [an issue a few months ago](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/issues/473) with probably the same problem but it's closed so I guess it should be fixed now

Comment: Maybe not related to your issue, but you don't fulfill with one of the two golden rules (they are stated in the docs): your login_path MUST be defined OUTSIDE the restricted area. Yours is at /_admin/, and your restricted area is at /_admin/.+ so you are not defining it outside.

Comment: I don't think so. Expression `/_admin/.+` doesn't match `/_admin/` path, so `/_admin/` is outside restricted area.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was getting the same exception when trying to register the `SecurityServiceProvider` before the `TwigServiceProvider`.

I just changed the registering order (*Security* **after** *Twig*) and everything started to work fine:

```
// Twig service

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => sprintf("%s/../views", __DIR__),
));

// Security service

$app["security.firewalls"] = array();
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
```

Comment: This actually doesn't register Twig extensions (like `is_granted`) for Symfony Security because `TwigServiceProvider` checkes whether `$app['security']` is set and since you're registering `SecurityServiceProvider` after `TwigServiceProvider` it won't add the extension to Twig.

Comment: You're right, this was a quick solution I used to get an app up and running when I couldn't find the reason behind the exception. KuiKui's answer seems to be more optimal.

Answer (score 13):

You have to boot your application between the `SecurityServiceProvider` registration and the `TwigServiceProvider` registration :

```
// Security service
$app["security.firewalls"] = array();
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());

// Boot your application
$app->boot();

// Twig service
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => sprintf("%s/../views", __DIR__),
));
```

This code above seems to fix your problem but you must at least add one authentication provider.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue - also with the current silex version ~2.7.

Finally I found out, that in my case the "symfony/twig-bridge" component integrated via composer was the problem. I integrated that twig-bridge component to use the *trans* trait in my twig templates for translation (e.g. `{{ 'Age'|trans }}`). After removing twig-bridge from the project all worked as expected.

In order to use trans in my templates I have implemented an I18nExtension for myself to still use the trait syntax:

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Utils;

class I18nExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    private $app;

    /**
     * Register the extension after registering the TwigServiceProvider by
     * $app['twig']->addExtension(new AppBundle\Utils\I18nExtension($app));
     */
    public function __construct(\Silex\Application $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    /**
     * Provide an additional simple filter called trans - calling 
     * the translate function specified below.
     */
    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('trans', array($this, 'translate')),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Translates the given $value using the translator registered in the app.
     */
    public function translate($value) {
        return $this->app['translator']->trans($value);
    }

    /**
     * Name of the extension.
     */
    public function getName() {
        return "I18nExtension";
    }
}
```