# Silex won't load Twig extensions

Tags: php, twig, silex

I'm using Silex and trying to use the `Intl` extension for Twig, but I get the following error when trying to use the `localizeddate` filter:

> The filter "localizeddate" does not exist in "games.html"

As per [these instructions](http://nerdpress.org/2014/05/05/enable-twig-extensions-silex-revisited/), my `composer.json` contains the following line in the `require` section:

```
 "twig/extensions": "~1.1.0"
```

My `app.php` file contains this:

```
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/../templates/'
));

$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl($app));

    return $twig;
}));
```

Finally, somewhere in my `games.html` template is this, which throws the error described above:

```
{{ game.start_time|localizeddate('medium', 'none', 'fr') }}
```

For the sake of testing, I also tried with the `Text` extension, exactly as in the linked instructions, but it generated the same kind of error.

The strange thing is I can put anything in the function where I add the extension; it will never generate any error as long as the syntax is valid. So, if I replace `$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl($app))` by `$twig->addExtension(new Foo())`, Silex doesn't seem to have a problem with it, even though the class `Foo` doesn't exist.

If I throw a `RuntimeException` in the constructor of the `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl` class, it doesn't show up either, so it seems the extension is never loaded in the first place. This line can be found in the `autoload_namespaces.php` file though: `'Twig_Extensions_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/extensions/lib')`.

I tried adding a basic `Twig_SimpleFilter` the same way, it doesn't work either, so it seems the way I'm trying to add this is just plain wrong, yet it's the way I find everywhere...

Comment: My best guess is that the `twig` service is being initialized before the extend is applied. Is there anything between the register call and the extend call?

Comment: There's nothing at all between them, unfortunately.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the service is being overwritten later. Try throwing an exception right after `$twig->addExtension()` Then immediately below the extend call, do `$app['twig'];` to instantiate the service. See if the exception gets thrown. If so, something else is overwriting the `twig` service down the line somewhere.

Comment: While testing this, I ended up coming across the error described in the question associated to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20748862/1657936), which solved the exception issue, but not the primary one described here.

If I do what you suggested, the exception gets thrown correctly, but once I remove the instanciation immediately after the extension, it goes right back to where we started, as predicted.

I have another extension for my `SessionServiceProvider` a little lower, but I tried commenting it out, same problem.

Comment: Instanciating Twig at the end of my `app.php` file throws the same `InvalidArgumentException` (`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Identifier "security.authentication_providers" is not defined.`).

Comment: Well, got it. I was apparently redefining Twig in my development config file. Don't know why the hell I did that. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The twig service is being redefined later on in the application boot process. (See question comments for debugging steps). The first time twig is being created, you are extending it and adding the extension. Later on, twig is getting defined *again*, but this time no extension is added.

The second definition overrides the first which is the primary problem. The confusing part is that the original extension never gets called. This is because Silex doesn't actually call your extension function **until the twig service is used**. Since you are overriding it before that happens, the extension function is never called. To debug, you called `$app['twig']` immediately after you defined twig the *first* time and ensured the extension got run. Through the process of elimination, that means that the twig service is getting overridden sometime later. You determined that that is in the config file.