# Silex won't display 404 error template after $app->boot()

Tags: silex

Based on [18022890](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022890/silex-securityserviceprovider-throws-identifier-security-authentication-provid#answer-20925212) this is my code.

```
/* Register service provider */
// ...
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider(), array(...));
$app->boot();
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(...));

/* Route collection */
// ....

/* Not found exception */
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {
    if ($app['debug']) return;

    $templates = array(
        'error/'.$code.'.twig',
        'error/'.substr($code, 0, 2).'x.twig',
        'error/'.substr($code, 0, 1).'xx.twig',
        'error/default.twig',
    );

    return new Response($app['twig']->resolveTemplate($templates)->render(array('code' => $code)), $code);
});
```

FYI: I got route collection from [here](https://gonzalo123.com/2013/03/04/scaling-silex-applications-part-ii-using-routecollection/).

Everything seems OK, except **http ://silex.local/undefinedroute** won't display my 404 error template. How to handle this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the registering order (Security **before** Twig) and without `$app->boot()` then my 404 error template shows up.

```
/* Register service provider */
// ...
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(...));
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider(), array(...));
```

Comment: You can't register the SecurityServiceProvider after calling the [*boot method*](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Application.php#L193) because the provider [won't boot](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php#L582) so it won't install the listener to intercept the request and start the security procedure.