# Silex: registering Twig and SecurityServiceProvider results in error

Tags: php, security, twig, silex

These are the lines of code that register the providers I'm using:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider, ['twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/../resources/views']);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
$app->register(new MenuServiceProvider(), ['knp_menu.views_path' => __DIR__ . '/../resources/views']);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider());
$app->register(new FormServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\AssetServiceProvider(), array(
    'assets.version' => 'v1',
    'assets.version_format' => '%s?version=%s',
    'assets.named_packages' => array(
        'css' => ['base_path' => Config::get('silex/baseUrl') . 'css/'],
        'img' => ['base_path' => Config::get('silex/baseUrl') . 'img/']
    ),
));

$app['security.firewalls'] = array();
```

This does not give a problem, when I load a controller like the following, no problems pops up.

```
$routes->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return 'Yes';
})->bind('home');
```

However, when I try to do something with twig: either add a Global or add a filter. An error displays on my screen.

```
$app['twig']->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('json_decode', function ($string) {
    return json_decode($string);
}));
```

This results in the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Identifier
>   "security.authentication_providers" is not defined. in
>   H:\Software\xamp\htdocs\UserSystem\vendor\pimple\pimple\src\Pimple\Container.php:96
>   Stack trace: #0

This is weird since there is no problem when I'm not adding a filter or global. I've found one case that's simular to this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022890/silex-securityserviceprovider-throws-identifier-security-authentication-provid). However, that solution does not seem to do the job for me. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you checked the second answer on the similar question you link to? It's not the accepted one, but it has more votes.

Comment: .Yes I've tried that one too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to add functionality to the service before booting up all providers and application. According to the [documentation](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/twig.html#customization) it should be done like this (Silex 2):

```
$app->extend('twig', function(Twig_Environment $twig, Application $app) {
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('json_decode', 'json_decode'));
    return $twig;
});
```

And for Silex 1.3:

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function(Twig_Environment $twig, Application $app) {
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('json_decode', 'json_decode'));
    return $twig;
}));
```